# Is there any configuration in chart.js v2 that allows bar's to start from some number instead of origin?

Tags: chart.js

I have a case where smaller the number, higher the value. Therefore, I wanted to build a bar chart where the bar starts from some negative value toward zero. Looking via Chart.js doc, I don't see any option for this use case, while in some comments, I saw few of the guys mentioning an option `barBeginAtOrigin:true` that could possible do this. But doesn't seems to work.

Doesn't anybody knows if it's even possible or not in Chart.js V2?

Update (More clarification):
[image]

Notice, the bar starts from sum 100,000 towards 1 or 0. Here 1 or 0 is considered really high number compared to 100,000. I don't think this feature is available out of the box in Chart.js V2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with [floating bars](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/charts/bar.html#data-structure) where individual bars are specified with the syntax `[min, max]`.

Given a `data` array, its values can easily be converted to the desired `data` property through the [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```
data: data.map(v => ([0, v]))
```

Please take a look at below runnable sample and see how it works.

```js
var data = [-5, -7, -3, -6, -2, -4, -3];

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Bars',
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)", "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)"],
      borderColor: ["rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(54, 162, 235)", "rgb(153, 102, 255)", "rgb(201, 203, 207)"],
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: data.map(v => ([0, v]))
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        position: 'top'
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: tooltipItem => data[tooltipItem.index]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```